# iOS Swift - TableView rows are blank

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am new to iOS dev and basically I'm trying to populate a TableView with String values from an array.

However when I run the app, blank rows show up and no text values are shown. Have I coded this correctly?

```
import UIKit

    class SelectIssueController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var issuesTableView: UITableView!

        var issues = [Issue]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.issues = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]

        self.issuesTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        }

        override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
            return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.issues.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = self.issuesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            cell.textLabel?.text = issues[indexPath.row]

            //Even if I manually set a value, the rows are still blank
            //cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"

            return cell

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set your SelectIssueController instance to be the UITableView's data source?

Comment: Are you talking about the Referencing outlets? @LucasDerraugh If so, yes I have :)

Comment: The tableView's dataSource either in the storyboard or  issuesTableView.datasource = self

Comment: Sorry, where is that located? @BenOng

Comment: Have you set `TableView dataSource` and `TableView delegate` to this view controller??

Comment: You can use it in viewDidLoad or anytime before the tableView is loaded, otherwise reload the tableView after it is set

Comment: Otherwise, go to storyboard and there is one outlet for datasource, drag it to the SelectIssueController and set it as datasource

Comment: Return static number of rows and add cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
Now, check if the data populates in Tableview. Also, check if you have connected datasource and delegates or not.

Comment: Set your Datasource and delegate to your VC\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Table view data source and delegate in two ways.
1. Click `Cntrl+drag` from `tableView` to `view controller`. See below figure

[image]

2. Create the `outlet` of your `tableView` and assign its datasource and delegate in `ViewDidLoad`.

In your example you already have an outlet to issuesTableView, so you would write:

```
issuesTableView.dataSource = self
issuesTableView.delegate = self
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Silly me! This fixed the problem haha :) I will accept it in 5 minutes

Comment: Happy coding:) @Dinuka

Comment: I took the liberty of updating your answer a little @Karthick, hope you don't mind (using `issuesTableView` instead of `myTableView` in suggestion 2)

Comment: @pbodsk. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks guys! @pbodsk and Karthick